# Preprocessing of a single image for prediction. ( CNN build and trained with Keras)

Tags: numpy, keras, conv-neural-network, opencv, python

Had a lack of understanding how to make a single prediction with existing trained model( keras Sequential.

The preprocessing and training of CNN looked like this:
    from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255,
                                   shear_range=0.2,
                                   zoom_range=0.2,
                                   horizontal_flip=True)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory('dataset/training_set',
                                                 target_size=(64, 64),
                                                 batch_size=32,
                                                 class_mode='binary')

test_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory('dataset/test_set',
                                            target_size=(64, 64),
                                            batch_size=32,
                                            class_mode='binary')

classifier.fit_generator(training_set,
                         steps_per_epoch=8000,
                         epochs=25,
                         validation_data=test_set,
                         validation_steps=2000)
```

As the predict_generator did not work I stucked...

Comment: Can you clarify your question? What do you mean by "did not work"?

Comment: Hi @NicoHaase yes sure, it did throw me an error of that it can't just take an image as required to have there an array( which was not there, just image was). I know that it was pretty dum to wait that image could be taken as a source to work with, but still I thought so... but afterwards I found an option with resizing and reshaping the image for evaluation! Thanks for your clarification btw

Answer (score 3):

```
import numpy as np
from keras.preprocessing import image

test_image = image.load_img('dataset/single_prediction/cat_or_dog_1.jpg', target_size(64,64))
test_image = image.img_to_array(test_image)
test_image = np.expand_dims(test_image,axis=0)
result = classifier.predict(test_image)
training_set.class_indices
```

Comment: If you need further pre-processing (e.g. rescaling) have a look at the keras ImageDataGenerator() implementation. It's quite understandable.

Comment: Missing an '=', I think:
      `image.load_img(..., target_size` **=** `(64,64))`

Answer (score 1):

After some googling I found that single image is better to preprocess with opencv, so went to its documentation, installed on mac via terminal( using conda).

```
conda install opencv
```

Next in code tried this:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

predict_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

img1 = cv2.imread('path_to_image/img_1.jpg')
img1 = cv2.resize(img1, (64, 64))
```

Knowing that model's image input shape was (64, 64, 3) after resizing I checked if the shape matches with

```
print(img1.shape)
```

It went out that all was good so I needed to add dimension to match model's requirements, that I figured out after receiving ValueError:

```
ValueError: Error when checking : expected conv2d_1_input to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (64, 64, 3)
```

So the image was reshaped:

```
img1 = np.array(img1).reshape((1, 64, 64, 3))#do not miss the order in tuple
```

After that I received the image of a needed shape and size and ready for a single prediction with `predict` method.