# cannot reshape array of size 983040 into shape (320,320,1)

Tags: python, numpy

```
img_size = 320
def load_img(path):
img = Image.open(path)
if img is None:
    raise ValueError(f"Empty Image at {path}")
img = img.convert("RGB")
return img
def load_data(path_list, gray=False, img_size=256):
data = []
for path in tqdm(path_list):
    img = load_img(path)
    if gray:
        img = img.convert("L")
    img = img.resize((img_size, img_size))
    img_array = np.array(img)
    if gray:
        img_array = img_array.reshape((img_size, img_size, 1))
    data.append(img_array)
return np.array(data)
X_train= load_data([images_dir +"/"+ x for x in X_train])

X_test= load_data([images_dir +"/"+ x for x in X_test])
Y_train= load_data([masks_dir + '/' + x for x in y_train], gray=True)/255.0
Y_test= load_data([masks_dir + '/' + x for x in y_test], gray=True)/255.0
Y_train= Y_train.reshape( -1,img_size, img_size, 1)
```

**Error**

```
----> 1 Y_train= Y_train.reshape( -1,img_size, img_size, 1)
  2 
  3 

ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 983040 into shape (320,320,1)
```

when i keep the image size 256 then the code runs well but when I change it to less than 256 or greater than 320 it generates the error can anyone tell me what's the issue

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Preprocessing of a single image for prediction. ( CNN build and trained with Keras)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51209343/preprocessing-of-a-single-image-for-prediction-cnn-build-and-trained-with-ker)

Comment: `reshape` cannot be used to resize an image.  I see you are already using `img.resize`.  If that's been done right, you shouldn't need further `reshape`.

Answer (score -1):

- The size of the array you're trying to reshape is determined by the number of elements it contains. In this case, the size of the array is 983040, which is calculated by multiplying the dimensions of the array together: `320 * 320 * 1 = 102400`
- You need to ensure that the size of the array matches the desired shape. In your code, you're resizing the images to a specific size (img_size) before converting them to an array. If you want to reshape the array to `(320, 320, 1)`, you need to make sure that the resized images have dimensions of `320x320`.
- You said the code runs well when the image size is 256, then it says the original images you're working with have dimensions of `256x256`. If you want to change the image size to less than `256` or greater than `320`, you need to ensure that the original images have dimensions that match the desired size.
- Alternatively, you can modify your code to handle images of different sizes by dynamically adjusting the reshape operation based on the actual size of the images. This way, you won't encounter errors when the image size is changed.